# Why does my bakes looking bad in Marmoset Toolbag?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, normal-map

I did [chamferzone's tutorial for game ready assets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bWQTf2MyYU) and everything was fine until marmoset 4, I did a preview bake and here is the result:

[image]

I tried to change the cage offset but nothing changed.

Baked Textures:

[image]

[image]

Blend File:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since the render engine is set to *Eevee*, I guess you are trying to bake in marmorset correct? If so, your objects are not named properly, make sure both names (low and high) are matching.

Comment: oh okay thank you so dont have any problem to my uv map or something